# Need to validate html styles

Tags: html, xslt

i am converting docx file into html using xslt. My resulting html contains styles like `margin-top:NaN pt;`, the style value `NaN` is ignored in browser by default.But i have to validate for the presence of such attributes and have to remove before viewing in browser...

Please help me...Thanks in advance...

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a general approach and a concrete example. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried W3C CSS validator?

- http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

You can use it programatically thanks to a SOAP Web service:

- http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/api.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check for 'NaN' **before** adding inline styles.

E.g. consider this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t>
    <Number>adsfdasf</Number>
    <Number></Number>
    <Number>100</Number>
    <Number>1.234234</Number>
</t>
```

Then you can:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' : ')"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(string(number()) = 'NaN')">valid</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string(number()) = 'NaN'">invalid</xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
adsfdasf : invalid
 : invalid
100 : valid
1.234234 : valid
```

Comment: +1 Good approach. I don't think that it's good to test string value of number function...

Comment: @Alejandro. I think it's more readable for a conventional-language-developer. Though I don't insist.

Answer (score 0):

It is too-late to chack for NaN in the generated result.

**Producing unwanted output should be prevented**!

Here is an example, that avoids generating NaN:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[number(.) = number(.)]">
  <span style="margin-top:{.}"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[not(number(.) = number(.))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <num>helo</num>
    <num></num>
    <num>100</num>
    <num>1.234234</num>
</t>
```

**only correct output (no NaN) is produced**:

```
<t>
   <span style="margin-top:100"/>
   <span style="margin-top:1.234234"/>
</t>
```